# Child class override parents parameters

Tags: python, class, inheritance

**Situation:** I have a function, I want to have a child with only one different default parameter. Is it possible to not rewrite every parameters and only the one that I want to change ?

```
class Weapon():
    def __init__(self, weight=12, ammo=22, name="shotgun",useful=True, broken=False, needed_lvl=5, range=2, price=233):
        pass # A LOT OF STUFF NOT INTERESTING FOR THIS EXAMPLE
```

**WORKING ANSWER BUT NOT EFFICIENT:** useless repeated information and can be easily break if one thing change in the parent.

```
class ShotGun(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, weight=12, ammo=12, name="shotgun",useful=True, broken=False, needed_lvl=5, range=2, price=233):
        pass # A LOT OF STUFF NOT INTERESTING FOR THIS EXAMPLE
```

**WANTED ANSWER:** If the user doesn't change anything, the default value of the parameter `ammo` should be `12`.

```
class ShotGun(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        pass # A LOT OF STUFF NOT INTERESTING FOR THIS EXAMPLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override only the specific argument. Just pass everything else to `super().__init__()`. But you still need to set the overriden attribute in the child class for the new default value to have any effect:

```
class Weapon():
    def __init__(self, weight=12, ammo=22, name="shotgun",useful=True, broken=False, needed_lvl=5, range=2, price=233):
        self.ammo = ammo
        self.name = "shotgun"


class ShotGun(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, ammo=12, **kwargs): # override only ammo
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ammo = ammo                   # use overriden value instead of parent

s = ShotGun()
print(s.ammo)
print(s.name)
```

Ouput:

```
12
shotgun
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could just precise it like this ! No luck that we need to rewrite `self.ammo` but that's still more clean than the first first option ! :)